# MWFeedParser in-app web browser INSTEAD of safari

Tags: iphone, rss, browser, in-app

So i'm using the MWFeedParser, which I think is a beautiful RSS feed app, but when clicking on a link it goes to Safari. I fear that a good portion of iPhone users are unaware of the fact that they can double-click on the iPhone's one and only button to view all open apps and go back to the RSS feed, and will thus get stuck. Therefore I'd rather use an in-app browser.

In other words, currently when I click on a link from MWFeedParser it goes to Safari; I prefer it goes to an in-app browser.

I have the browser class set up called WebViewController.
basically with **[detailWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:detailURL]];**
So "detailURL" is what it will look for

What do I put in the DetailTableViewController instead of the sharedApplication code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bummer nobody was able to answer...in case others are looking for how to do it, change the contents of **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** to

```
if (_webViewController == nil) {
        self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    }

    MWFeedItem *entry = [parsedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _webViewController.entry = entry;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];


    // Deselect
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Add a WebViewController;
the .m has

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "MWFeedItem.h"
@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize entry = _entry;

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.link];    
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [_entry release];
    _entry = nil;
    [_webView release];
    _webView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And the .h has

```
@class MWFeedItem;

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {
    UIWebView *_webView;
    MWFeedItem *_entry;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (retain) MWFeedItem *entry;
```

(Basically I just took the webview part of Ray Wenderlich's RSS feeder and threw it in to this one.)