# Which is the best method to parse RSS Feeds in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make an iphone application for a blog. Which is the best method to parse the RSS feeds from the blog.

Answer (score 6):

Just use this MWFeedParser

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

In the RootViewController files, under **(void)viewDidLoad** edit the line, and put your full URL

```
NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:http://www.YOUR_URL_HERE.com/whateverRSS"];
```

Another good parser is from Ray Wenderlich
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

I actually combined the 2 since I liked the parsing of MWFeedParser but Ray's went to an UIWebView instead of Safari, this link describes how to combine
[MWFeedParser in-app web browser INSTEAD of safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985591/mwfeedparser-in-app-web-browser-instead-of-safari)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I use this in several of my apps, and I am pleased with the performance. [JSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) is also a good library to use.

Comment: JSON for RSS? I think only XMLis used for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use XML Translator from [CWFoundation project](https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation/), but then I made it. The project has a RSS parser (for Apple news feed) as a sample app. I honestly believe that there is no easier way to parse XML into proper domain objects for Objective-C, at least none that I have the last decade.