# Load RSS from multiple feeds in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, nsxmlparser

I want to start to create an app that allows the user to read feeds from multiple sites. The user can add a new feed and all the news from all stored feeds will be presented in a tableview. Thus, i wanted to ask if it is possible to  a way to load the content from multiple xml feeds into one feed and order it by date of publish?

What would be the best approach?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the best method to parse RSS Feeds in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585993/which-is-the-best-method-to-parse-rss-feeds-in-iphone)

Comment: For multiple feeds, you can ( should ) load them either feed by feed, or in parallel in different processes.

Comment: Parse all feeds into custom objects and add those to an array. Then you can use for example NSSortDescriptor to sort by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping all feeds into one is usually a bad call if you want to have reasonable latency as grouping usually means caching of each individual feeds before they're grouped.